# Sencha Touch chart - How to add label/value in column chart

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-charts

I am using Sencha Touch charts 1.0.0 for my project. I would like to add values on each bar in the column chart. Is is possible to do ?

For example, see the image: I would like to add the values for each bar.

[image: Sample chart]

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this in yoour series config

```
 label: {
                display: 'outside', 
                field: 'score',
                orientation: 'horizontal', // 'vertical'
                text-anchor': 'middle'
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Just needed to change `field` to `['unit1', 'unit2']` to have this displayed on second bar in the group.

Answer (score 0):

Label config is not work for me.

I used `labelField:'comedy'` in series it work.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this problem and found this solution didn't work. I'm using Touch Charts 2.0

This **does** work:

```
labelField: 'MyDataValue'
```

However, this does **not** work:

```
label: {
    display: 'outside', 
    field: 'score',
    orientation: 'horizontal', // 'vertical'
    text-anchor': 'middle'
}
```

According to Sencha 2.2.1 docs (latest at time of writing), the default for label config is:

```
label: {
    textBaseline: 'middle',
    textAlign: 'center',
    font: '14px Helvetica'
}
```

This suggests slightly different formatting params to those suggested by Nag. Maybe this is a change since v 1.x or it may to do with differences between **Touch** and **ExtJS**
Anyway - hope it helps someone.