# Sencha Touch chart - How to add label/value in line chart

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-charts

I am using Sencha Touch charts 1.0.0 for my project. I would like to add values on each point in my line chart (as in image). I tried the same approach in [this question for column chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612725/sencha-touch-chart-how-to-add-label-value-in-column-chart), but it didn't work out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with you. But i find a solution instead for that. You can add marker at each node of line and when you click on marker a popup will show detail information as you want. This's my code may help you :

-Add marker in cofig of series :

```
type: 'line',
            title: 'Clickeds : ' + total[4] + ' ( ' + Math.round(arrInfo[4]) + '% )',
            highlightCfg: { scale : 0.7 },
            xField: 'Date', yField: 'Clks',
            style : {
                stroke: 'rgb(50, 185, 150)',
                miterLimit : 3,
                lineCap: 'miter',
                lineWidth: 2
            }
            ,
            marker:{
                type: 'image',
                src: 'resources/images/square.png',
                width: 24,
                height: 24,
                x: -12,
                y: -12,
                scale: 0.5,
                fx: {
                    duration: 200
                }
            }
```

- Handle event when you click on node, you add listeners to config of chart : `listeners: {
              itemtap: function( series, item, event, eOpts ){
                                //handle your code here.

  ```
                             }`
  ```

Regards,
(Sorry for bad english.)